# Perplexity for different n-gram models

Tags: natural-language, language-models, perplexity, nltk

I'm training a Lidstone Model with different n-gram sequences to see witch one is the best (2-gram, 3-gram, 4-gram, etc) in the same [text database](https://github.com/cpdoc/dhbb).

When I give all these models an unseen text sample from the same database and ask for the perplexity of the n-grams contained in these text, witch perplexity should I expect to be higher?

*(Asking to check if my results make sense.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to say. Increasing n [trades off variance in exchange for less bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram#Bias-versus-variance_trade-off). The only way to know whether increasing n reduces perplexity is by already knowing how exactly how the text was generated.

In practice, unigram models tend to underfit on non-trivial text datasets. 10-gram models trained on small datasets tend to overfit. It's difficult and not really useful to hypothesize about 2,3,4-gram models. Empirically evaluating each on a large independent sample is easy and sufficient.